# Can not see iAd in program?

Tags: iphone, app-store

My app has just released on Appstore ( http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/i-shock/id383457769?mt=8) . It runs with an iAd banner but I can not see it when I download from Appstore to my device (of course, network is working).

The status in iAd Network is "Live: This app is receiving live ads.". iAd preferences was typed.

My original code is running well on device with a iAd test banner.

Did I make somethings wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the exact same problem, but itunesConnect shows 0 request. I tried leaving the app on for 5 hours, and i did not get a single request. Can you please tell me how long did u wait until your app started receiving requests? thanks

Answer (score 3):

A number of developers are noting that the fill rate is currently very low. Also note that they are only live in the US.

If it works correctly in test then it's *probably* okay. I believe the analytics available in iTunes Connect shows the number of requests as well as the number of fills and clicks.

Comment: Thanks Stephen Darlington, I check in iTunes Connect, there are some requests. It means iAd in my program working well although some people can not see it?

Comment: Yes, I think that's what's happening. I would imagine (hope) that as Apple get more advertisers the fill rate will rise. I'm going to put "house" ads -- advertising my other programs -- in my apps when Apple doesn't return an ad.