# iAd not showing up on my app I just released

Tags: iphone, iad

Ok so I went out on a limb with the iAd craze and released my a new app for free with iad support. It took me forever to figure out how to setup everything up so that the banner "only shows when there is an ad to show".

Now my app is live and I am not seeing any banner! Does apple just occasionally decide to throw you a bone every now and then and give you an ad to show? How does it work? Does the fact that nothing is showing up in my app currently mean that the iads aren't working, or just hiding properly? Please help!

Ps- I am running ios 4 on my 2g 8gb iPod touch...can iads not run on the iPod?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can not see iAd in program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361464/can-not-see-iad-in-program)

Comment: As has been pointed out in the several other questions that ask something similar, there is a limited ad inventory right now.  In addition to that, the targeted nature of the ads may mean that the keywords and / or age target of your application don't match the available ads.

Comment: @BradLarson as I mention below, Apple seems to delay about 24-32 hours before serving ads in a live application for the first time. I think/hope that limited inventory is no longer a problem three years later.

Thanks as always for the interaction.

Answer (score 2):

iAd is not shown up if your app is just released. It takes a few more days for iAd appropriateness review. Once iAd approved your app you'll see requests in iAd reporting page. I waited for 3 days for my first iAd supported app to see its first requests.

Let's assume you implemented and tested iAd well in your app and there is no network connection issue here.

Answer (score 1):

As I known, you can see iAd banner if you are running the iPhone/iPod app in US.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that this might due to limited inventory of ads: [Can not see iAd in program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361464/can-not-see-iad-in-program)

Answer (score 1):

I just released the first version of my app ([MIDI Designer Lite](https://itunes.apple.com/app/midi-designer-lite-professional/id492292826?mt=8)) with iAds yesterday. **The iAds took over 24 hours to begin showing**.

Of course you have to make sure that iAds are showing in your test app, and also that you've got "iAd Advertising Network Enabled" in iTunes Connect for the app in question.

**Note:** you can find out all metrics of iAds serving in your app and make adjustments [here](https://iad.apple.com/itcportal/).

(P.S. iPod touch can serve ads as well as any other device)

Comment: I don't see anywhere to set "iAd Advertising Network Enabled" in iTunes Connect.

Comment: @TomKincaid yep, they move stuff around constantly. This answer was from Jan 2014.

Answer (score 1):

I've just released an App and am seeing the same thing - I went to the iAD workbench and saw this message:

> iADWorkbench: When you submit your app for approval, it will also be
>   reviewed by iAd for use on the App Network to determine its
>   appropriateness for receiving ads from iAd advertisers. Once your app
>   is approved, you will be ready to start earning revenue for ads that
>   run in your app.

But I have also done as @markussvensson suggests and just ask them if there's anything wrong.

Update: Received a helpful response from Apple:

> After your app is approved and ready for sale, it is reviewed by iAd
>   to determine its appropriateness for receiving ads from iAd
>   advertisers. This process takes a few days.
>
> After your app is approved by iAd, you may begin to see ad
>   impressions. You can monitor ad performance and revenue generated at
>   any time from the iAd reporting module in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

The iAds review process seems to be disconnected from the AppStore. I had one app that was approved and ready to serve live ads.

[image]

But no requests were coming, even after waiting the suggested 4-5 days. After communicating with Apple, it turned out the app has been classified as “designed for children” and therefore not allowed to serve iAds (according to the iAds policy https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/iad-app-network/).
Note that the classification is not connected to the classification “Made for kids” in AppStore.

Summary: It could be that your app was not approved by iAds. No one will tell you until you contact Apple.