# iphone iAd question?

Tags: iphone, iad

My application got approved yesterday. before they start reviewing test ads were showing up on my app (device), but as soon as they start reviewing ads stopped showing on the device.

My app is finally approved and iAd is enabled, but i haven't seen a single ad since yesterday. Does it take some time after app is proved until my app starts receiveing ads? i checked itunes connect and it shows 0 requests.
Any idea why I'm not receiving ads?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can not see iAd in program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361464/can-not-see-iad-in-program)

Comment: very similar but not a duplicate, i get 0 requests the other person gets request but no impressions

Answer (score 0):

iAds will show test ads until Apple approve the application. Once the application is approved, the iAds will be switched to live.

You didn't mention your location...

As far as I'm aware, iAds are still only showing for users that live in the USA. Even then, the fill rate for iAds have been shown to be around 10-11% (not very high at all).

This means that for every 100 ad requests received, only 10 or 11 are going to actually show an iAd. the other 90-89% will show nothing.

Hopefully the fill rate will start to improve as Apple's ad inventory increases in size.

The other issue is that it seems the iAd framework will not show repeat adverts. That is to say that once a particular iAd has been shown, it won't be shown again on that device for that session (the length of a session is vague too...).

So, check your location, check your current fill rate on the iTunes Connect iAd section.

Comment: I live in USA. I left my app open for 2 hours and i didn't get a single ad. I had over 200 users using my application since yesterday, so out of these 200 users at least 1 of them must have seen a single ad. itunesconnect shows 0 requests.
Anyways I'm going to wait for a few days, and then probably contact apple.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any requests in itunesconnect->iAd.

If you don't have any requests, there's probably something wrong with your code.

Does the test ad show up when running in the simulator?

Comment: yes the test ads show up in the simulator
there are 0 requests

Answer (score 0):

The fill rate is low as mentioned before. Did you use the code that apple needed you to use as in the delegate and all for not loading when there is no iAd. If so try downloading the app onto your device and run it a few times. See if you get no ad at all

Comment: I am using Mobclix for add. How can i check programmatically whether the add is running or not ? any idea ? Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my app at one point too. I was using Mobclix to serve iAds. I was getting other ads, but none from iAd. Eventually, I realized my problem was that I did not have the iAd Framework linked to my project. That made the ads show up perfectly. I ended up weak linking the iAd Framework because I had to support devices with OS < 4.0. Hope this helps!

Comment: i have also used Mobclix in my iphone app. But how can i check whether the add is running or not, programmatically ? Thanks..