# Admob mediation iAd testing

Tags: admob, iad

I seem to have admob mediation working fine.  I would prefer to have iAd first then admob fill after.  The issue is that I’m getting zero iAd requests in iTunes connect.  I even put the percentage to 100%.  I have it enabled and everything in admob.  Anyone know how I can test iAd with admob mediation?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is probably not in admob mediation but iAd fill rates. Their fill rates have historically been pretty low and recently this year, its dropped down to about 5% for a lot of apps.

See this answer
[Can not see iAd in program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361464/can-not-see-iad-in-program)

Answer (score 0):

That's impossible. I'm keeping admob at low settings 10% so most ads comes from other networks.